# Java - "the method ___ is undefined for the type ___"

Tags: java, methods, undefined

I'm building a simple genetic algorithm based off [this guide](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/creating-a-genetic-algorithm-for-beginners/3). I have made an 'Individual' class, which is as follows.

```
package simpleGA;

public class Individual {
    
    public static int defaultGeneLength = 64;
    
    private static byte genes[] = new byte[defaultGeneLength];
    
    private int fitness = 0;
    
    public void generateIndividual(){
        for (int i = 0; i < defaultGeneLength; i++){
            byte gene = (byte) Math.round(Math.random());
            genes[i] = gene;
        }
    }
    
    public byte getGene(int index) {
        return genes[index];
    }
    
    public int size(){
        return genes.length;
    }
    
    public int getFitness(){
        if (fitness == 0){
            fitness = FitnessCalc.getFitness(this);
        }
        return fitness;
    }
}
```

I have also made a class called 'FitnessCalc', which is as follows.

```
package simpleGA;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FitnessCalc {

    static byte[] solution = new byte[64];
    
    static String newSolution;
    
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    static void setSolution(){
        do{
            newSolution = null;
            System.out.println("Please enter a string of '1's and '0's of length 64.");
            newSolution = input.next();
        }
        while(newSolution.length() != 64);
        solution = new byte[newSolution.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < newSolution.length(); i++) {
            String character = newSolution.substring(i, i + 1);
            solution[i] = Byte.parseByte(character);
            }
    }
    
    static int getFitness(Individual individual){
        int fitness = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < solution.length && i < individual.size(); i++) {
            if (individual.getGene(i) == solution[i]) {
                fitness++;
            }
        }
        return fitness;
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the `getFitness` method in the 'FitnessCalc' class, the compiler returns an error for both the `size` and `getGene` methods, saying

"The method size() is undefined for the type Individual" and

"The method getGene(int) is undefined for the type Individual".

I'm not sure what this means. I've looked at other questions like this but none of the scenarios seem to relate to mine. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

After cleaning and rebuilding the project (I am using Eclipse), the errors remained, and a new error in my remaining class, 'Population', has appeared.

```
package simpleGA;

public class Population {

    Individual[] individuals;
    
    public Population (int populationSize, boolean initialise){
        individuals = new Individual[populationSize];
        if (initialise){
            for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
                Individual newIndividual = new Individual();
                newIndividual.generateIndividual();
                saveIndividual(i, newIndividual);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public int size(){
        return individuals.length;
    }
    
    public void saveIndividual(int index, Individual indiv){
        individuals[index] = indiv;
    }
}
```

The error is with the `generateIndividual` method being called in the `Population` method, and says the same as the other two:

"The method generateIndividual() is undefined for the type Individual".

The `generateIndividual` method is defined in the 'Individual' class.

Comment: this is some weird code. Class A uses class B, and class B uses class A. This means maybe you need to recompile both your classes, start with Individual, since that might be the one still using an older class.

Comment: You should be able to recompile both at once: `javac simpleGA/*.java`

Comment: It would be best to redesign this code so that only one class depends on the other.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I recompiled, cleaned and rebuilt the project, and another error occurred, which I have described in the edit. If I can't find a solution then I'll rewrite the code so the classes are less dependent on each other.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone wondering, I got rid of the issue by rewriting the code slightly. I moved the `getFitness` method over to the 'Individual' class, and that seemed to work. After this I made sure that the 'Individual' class only used methods from within its own class, so that classes weren't dependent on each other.